# Cloud SQL Connection + Auto Scaling

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

Per [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/compute-engine-access), Cloud SQL requires the external IP address of the client in order to allow connections to it. The other suggested way is the sql proxy with a big disclaimer that the method may change over time.

Question: If I am auto scaling compute engine VMs running webservers, do I need to assign them all external IPs and then go set those in the Cloud SQL instance? Or am I missing something huge? Noob question perhaps, thanks for reading through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way is to use the Cloud SQL proxy (but if you really don't want to use it you would need to add static IPs to your GCE VMs and whitelist them on the Cloud SQL instance).

Comment: I will probably end up with proxies, just that they sounded a bit tentative. I am surprised they haven't come up with a more reliable method. The static IP method is clumsy at best considering it may take some time for the IP based permissions to start reflecting which means the auto created instance will not be able to connect to sql immediately but LB will be sending web traffic to it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The Cloud SQL Proxy is not tentative -- it's the recommended way to connect from machines with ephemeral IPs (I'm from the Cloud SQL team)

Comment: Ok cool, I set it up already, good to know it wont go away. thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can setup a single VM instance with cloud_sql_proxy and listen to your subnet interface (for example) to make possible to connect any new VM instance to the one with a proxy.